# ColumnTypeUndefinedError in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, typescript, typeorm

Why on launch my project I get this error:

> ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Order#author is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.

here is my column like above,

```
    @Column({
        nullable: true
    })
    author: User;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go in your `tsconfig` file and uncomment `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,` then after go in your application entry file forexample app.ts or index.ts or server.ts depending on how you called it and import `reflect-metadata`  as below

```
import "reflect-metadata";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the **database** does not know about `User` type.

Change `User` to `string` and the error will go away, because the database knows about `string`:

```
@Column({
        nullable: true
    })
    author: string;
```

If you want `User` instead of `string`, use @ManyToOne instead of @Column. This sets up a foreign key relationship to the User table, and if you add `eager: true` the `User` entity will be loaded automatically with the base entity when you use any of the TypeOrm `find*` methods:

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, { eager: true })
author: User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the type in your column like this:

```
@Column({
  type: 'varchar',
  nullable: true
})
author: User;
```

Answer (score -1):

you are getting this error because your **tsconfig.json** file is not properly configured. add the following to your file.

```
{
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],  
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5", 
}
```

then you have to run

> npm run tsc

after you've editted your tsconfig file, for recompilation.