# Do you not have to type FK columns?

Tags: typeorm

I was previously running into an issue where I had to specifically type my columns each time I defined them in an Entity. Thankfully I ran into this Stackoverflow post which helped: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428004/columntypeundefinederror-in-typeorm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428004/columntypeundefinederror-in-typeorm%60), but do you not need to type columns that are a `@ManyToOne or @OneToMany` in the same way?

For example, here are the two entities that I had to type specifically

```js
@Entity()
export class ExerciseTypeEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'int',
  })
  id!: number;
  description!: string;
  @OneToMany(
    () => ExerciseEntity,
    (exerciseEntity) => exerciseEntity.exerciseType,
  )
  exercise!: ExerciseEntity[];
}

@Entity()
export class ExerciseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'int',
  })
  id!: number;
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  exerciseName!: string;
  @ManyToOne(
    () => ExerciseTypeEntity,
    (exerciseTypeEntity) => exerciseTypeEntity.id,
  )
  exerciseType!: ExerciseTypeEntity;
}
```